# Floatbox (lightbox) Gallery Order and Isotope

Tags: lightbox, jquery-isotope

Although this question is specific to Floatbox (http://floatboxjs.com/demo), this issue would be generic to most image gallery light-boxes.

I need Floatbox to be able to show my image galleries per Isotope's reordering of page elements; e.g. div - thumbs. For what Isotope does please see http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/sorting.html .

The problem is that plugins, like Floatbox, get their page order of elements (thumbnails) off of the initial div's on the page. From what I can understand of Isotope, it doesn't actually rewrite the HTML to allow scripts like Floatbox to the read/parse the new order of displayed thumbnails.

I only have a very black box understanding of jQuery so I suppose I am asking if there is a way to rewrite the page such that scripts like Floatbox can then be called to parse them in Isotopes new 'displayed' order.

I have hunted everywhere for a solution, but I cannot even find much in the way of anyone asking this question. That seems odd as this affects everyone who uses a Masonry/Isotope and lightbox combo ~ being able to advance via a lightbox in the newly sorted order instead of the original page order.

For what it's worth, the site with the galleries I am working on is leo labelle dot com.

PS - I posted a similar question to the creator of Floatbox and unfortunately his best solution was to rewrite the pages in each possible order  . . . yikes!!!!

Regardless of a solution - A huge thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you add a little more informationÉ

Comment: If you click on the link (http://leolabelle.com/Leo-Gallery-Sculpture.php) you will see a thumbnail gallery. Hover over 'Gallery Options' and you can reorder the thumbnails via the jQuery Isotope. Clicking on a thumbnail will zoom it via Floatbox. Advancing the thumbnails prev or next does not go in the new order of the thumbnails - it stays in the order that the page was originally written. I'm looking for a solution that will allow Floatbox to read the 'new' order.

Comment: This is a good question. I'm really interested in building a gallery of thumbnails that can be filtered using isotope and viewed using a lightbox of some flavour.